# " Error parsing XML: unbound prefix " while using AdView

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to use the Adview in my Android application. But now I am getting problem.
Here is my codes from xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/category_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#A0C3FF"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The same type of code was working well in next xml file.
But not here.
Can you please show me if I have done wrong anywhere as I myself could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this but I got the solution.
I had missed to include

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Now the code looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Cheers..